# Prestashop - Using ObjectModel inside FrontController

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing a Prestashop module:

[image]

And I created an OjectModel (`DnDPayment.php`) to handle all Db interaction. The problem is that I'm unable to create a new instance of this class within my FrontController file.

This is my FrontController (`payments.php`):

```
<?php

class DnDPaymentsPaymentsModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController {

    public function initContent() {
        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate('pay.tpl');
    }

     public function postProcess() {

         if (Tools::isSubmit('send-payment-btn')) {
            $bank = Tools::getValue('bank');
            $payer = Tools::getValue('payer');
            $amount = Tools::getValue('amount');
            $reference = Tools::getValue('reference');

            if (!$bank || !$payer || !$amount || !$reference)
                return $this->context->smarty->assign(array("error" => true));

            DnDPayment::savePayment(Tools::getValue('bank'),         Tools::getValue('payer'), Tools::getValue('amount'),   Tools::getValue('reference'));

            return $this->context->smarty->assign(array("ok" => true));
         }
     }
}
```

For now, I'm using the `savePayment` static method, but what I would really like is to create a new object and add it to the database like this:

```
....
$payment = new DnDPayment();
$payment->bank = "bah...";
....
....
try {
    $payment->add();
} catch(Exception $e) {
     //Handle error
}
```

But if I try this code, it will return a **500 error** and nothing more. It seems that the problem is the line with the `new` statement. If I try this code in my module file (`dndpayments.php`), then it works ok, but I want to use it in the front controller.

This is my Object Model (`DnDPayments.php`), just in case:

```
<?php


class DnDPayment extends ObjectModel {

    public $id;
    public $id_dnd_payments;
    public $bank;
    public $payer;
    public $amount;
    public $reference;
    public $date_add;

    public static $definition_array = array(
        'table' => 'dnd_payments',
        'primary' => 'id_dnd_payments',
        'multilang' => false,
        'fields' => array(
            'bank' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'payer' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'amount' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'reference' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
            'date_add' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING)
        )
    );

    public static function savePayment($bank, $payer, $amount, $reference) {
        $logger = new FileLogger(0);
        $logger->setFilename(_PS_ROOT_DIR_ . "/log/debug.log");
        $logger->logDebug($bank . ' :: ' . $payer . ' :: ' . $amount);

        Db::getInstance()->insert('dnd_payments', array(
            'bank' => $bank,
            'payer' => $payer,
            'amount' => $amount,
            'reference' => $reference,
            'date_add' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ));
    }
}
```

How can I instantiate a new ObjectModel in my controller and save it to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Have you included this class file in your controller before instantiating? If not, please include it and try again.

If You have already included your class file in your controller then check name of class and scope of definitions as well as function of your class file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include your class at the beginning of your controller file:

```
include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'dndpayments/classes/DnDPayment.php');
```

Prestashop load classes automatically but this is not a core class so you must include it manually.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but it is already being included from the main module file. It turns out it was the line `public static $definition_array = array(` that was wrong, thus, nos really defining the model. It should have been `public static $definition = array(` Without the `_array`.